# how to load a libsvm file using python ( fill missing values)

Tags: python, file

Let v = [10:1, 15:2, 20:3]; (i = [0, 1, 2] the indices of the values in the list)

- `n = 10 - (i + 1) = 10 - (0 + 1) = 9 ==> newV = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`
- `n = 15 - (9 + i + 1) = 15 - (9 + 1 + 1) = 4 ==> newV =[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]`
- `n = 20 - ( 9 + 4 + 2 + 1 ) = 20 - 16 = 4 ==> newV =[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]`

---

```
finalV = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]`
```

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = ['1:1', '15:2', '30:3']
    previous_Idx = []
    newV = []
    for i in  range(0, len(v)):
      idx = int(v[i].split(':')[0])
      val = float(v[i].split(':')[-1])
      n = idx - (sum(previous_Idx) + i + 1)
      for _ in range(n):
         newV.append(0)
      previous_Idx.append(n)
      newV.append(val)
    print newV
```

---

thank you pencil and paper.

Comment: Sounds like you might want [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: what is the expected output? and what've tried so far?

Comment: This is a little bit close to what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some unclear points in your question but here is a possible solution

```
for line in open("file.txt", 'r').readlines():
    line = line.strip().split(" ")
    lineName = line.pop(0)
    arr = [0.0] * int(line[-1].split(":")[0])  # fills the array with zeros

    for element in line:
        index,value = element.split(":")
        arr[int(index)-1] = float(value)

    print lineName + " " + " ".join(map(str, arr))  # /questions/6507431
```

Comment: thank you for your help what is unclear to modify it?

Comment: my implementation is totaly wrong sheesh it's depressing

Comment: what do you think of my implemenation?